# How can I look for attributes that are not exact within a particular grouping?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I am looking to identify all instances of an attribute where the value is not equal within a group. For example:

```
+------------+---------+------------+
|group_id    |  area   |     pip    |
+------------+---------+------------+
|  432       |  23     |  jack      |
|  432       |  23     |  jack      |
|  745       |  45     |  bill      |
|  745       |  45     |  bill      |
|  848       |  67     |  lynn      |
|  848       |  65     |  lynn      |
|  23        |  33     |  hop       |
|  23        |  33     |  hope      |
|  670       |  893    |  sue       |
|  670       |  893    |  sue       |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

What I need to know is, all attributes that are different within a group ID.  So the output table should be:

```
+------------+---------+------------+
|group_id    |  area   |     pip    |
+------------+---------+------------+
|  848       |  67     |  lynn      |
|  848       |  65     |  lynn      |
|  23        |  33     |  hop       |
|  23        |  33     |  hope      |
+------------+---------+------------+
```

This is the output because the area for group_id 848 is different, and the pip for group 23 is misspelled.  I would also like to return all fields (as I have more than 3 I am looking at).  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In this solution the only thing you have to do in order to support additional attributes, is to add them to this part -
`order by area,pip,...`

```
select      *

from       (select      t.*
                       ,min (rnk) over (partition by group_id)  as min_rnk
                       ,max (rnk) over (partition by group_id)  as max_rnk

            from       (select      t.*
                                   ,rank () over (partition by group_id order by area,pip)  as rnk

                        from        t
                        ) t
            ) t

where       min_rnk <> max_rnk
;
```

or

```
select      *

from       (select      t.*
                       ,count (distinct rnk) over (partition by group_id)  as distinct_rnk

            from       (select      t.*
                                   ,rank () over (partition by group_id order by area,pip)  as rnk

                        from        t
                        ) t
            ) t

where       distinct_rnk > 1
;
```

The `count (distinct rnk)` is more natural to understand but may involve significant performance penalty

Answer (score 1):

Use window functions to get the aggregated information needed:

```
select group_id, area, pip, colx, coly, colz, ...
from
(
  select 
    mytable.*,
    count(distinct area) over (partition by group_id) as count_area,
    count(distinct pip) over (partition by group_id) as count_pip
  from mytable
)
where count_area > 1 or count_pip > 1;
```

Comment: window functions in `where` clause?

Answer (score 0):

I'd first get groups that have more than 1 pip or area:

```
select group_id, area from table group by group_id having count(distinct pip) > 1 union all
select group_id, area from table group by group_id having count(distinct area) > 1;
```

And then join it with source table:

```
select t1.* from table t1 
            inner join (select group_id, area from table group by group_id having count(distinct pip) > 1 union all
                        select group_id, area from table group by group_id having count(distinct area) > 1) t2 
            on (t1.group_id = t2.group_id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Since you need to "count distinct" over more than one column, which is not an option in Oracle SQL, you need a trick. Here I concatenated the two columns, with a ~ between them; it should be a character that cannot be the last character of "area", for example.

```
with
     test_data ( group_id, area, pip ) as (
       select 432,  23, 'jack' from dual union all   
       select 432,  23, 'jack' from dual union all      
       select 745,  45, 'bill' from dual union all
       select 745,  45, 'bill' from dual union all
       select 848,  67, 'lynn' from dual union all
       select 848,  65, 'lynn' from dual union all
       select  23,  33, 'hop'  from dual union all
       select  23,  33, 'hope' from dual union all
       select 670, 893, 'sue'  from dual union all
       select 670, 893, 'sue'  from dual
     )
-- end of test data; solution (SQL query) begins below this line
select group_id, area, pip
from   (  select group_id, area, pip,
                 count(distinct to_char(area) || '~' || pip) 
                       over (partition by group_id) as ct
          from   test_data
       )
where  ct > 1
;

GROUP_ID  AREA  PIP
--------  ----  ----
      23    33  hop
      23    33  hope
     848    65  lynn
     848    67  lynn
```

Comment: ... or, since you don't really need the count(distinct), you just need to see if that count is greater than 1.... you can count separately for each column, as Thorsten has done.

Comment: Hello, just wanted to ask a quick question.  Is there a significant difference in your code and Dudu Markovitz 's code?  I ask, because they are both returning the same # of records, while some of the other's are returning less.  The reason I am leaning towards his, is because it allowed me to view all attributes in a record (there are over 20). As I am trying to learn SQL, I was just wondering if you could point out what yours is doing.

Comment: @user7002207 - I don't see why Thorsten's solution wouldn't give you the right answer; are you sure you adapted it correctly to your situation, with over 20 attributes per record? In any case: My solution looks at each `group_id` separately ("partition by"); then, it concatenates `area` and `pip` and it counts how many distinct values there are for each `group_id`. To see how that looks, select just the SUBQUERY from my solution and run it by itself, you will see a new column `ct` that gives this count.

Comment: And then I select only the rows that have a count greater than 1 (1 means that all attributes are the same for that `group_id` whether the `group_id` had one row or two or a hundred in the base table). Dudu's solution is similar - it partitions by `group_id` but then it orders the rows by the attributes, and gives a rank to each row (where "duplicates" will get the same rank). This then gets complicated, because he needs to select the min rank and the max rank, and compare that they are not the same to conclude there were rows with different attributes. Right idea, just not the simplest way.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is near all other Solutions, but I hope easier to understand.

1st step: Find all rows, that are totally equal

2nd step: Find all Group_ids from step 1 with more than 1 row

last step: join all data rows and all duplicate groups

```
WITH 
MyData AS (
  SELECT 432 group_id, 23 area,'jack' pip from dual union all
  SELECT 432, 23,'jack' from dual union all
  SELECT 745, 45,'bill' from dual union all
  SELECT 745, 45,'bill' from dual union all
  SELECT 848, 67,'lynn' from dual union all
  SELECT 848, 65,'lynn' from dual union all
  SELECT 23, 33,'hop' from dual union all
  SELECT 23, 33,'hope' from dual union all
  SELECT 670, 893,'sue' from dual union all
  SELECT 670, 893,'sue' from dual union all
  SELECT 999, 123,'andreas' from dual 
), 
-- End of Data
MyEqualGroups AS (
  SELECT GROUP_ID, AREA, PIP FROM MyData GROUP BY GROUP_ID, AREA, PIP 
),
MyUnequalGroups AS (
  SELECT GROUP_ID, COUNT(*) FROM MyEqualGroups GROUP BY GROUP_ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
)
SELECT * 
FROM MyData D
JOIN MyUnequalGroups UG ON D.GROUP_ID = UG.GROUP_ID
;
```